# #states doesn't work with Aggregate JavaScript

Tags: css-js-aggregation

Recently I have encountered the strange behavior of setting form created with Form API in Drupal 8.

I am using #states to hide one of the form elements ( radios ) when another element is empty. The problem is - it doesn't work with Aggregate JavaScript files option. After you submit the form, this element is still visible - even if condition to hide it is fulfilled.

When I disable Aggregate JavaScript files option, it works as expected - radios are hidden.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried on a fresh site? It's definitely not a core bug or none of the admin forms would work properly when aggregation was turned on (and they do). What other modules do you have installed that could mess with forms or JS?

Comment: Currently my module is only one that is 'extra'.

Comment: And when you disable your own module is the problem still there? With forms other than your own I mean?

Comment: I have checked only my module but never noticed similar behavior in the different module ( when I was skimming thru other options ). The thing is I'm not using Drupal on a daily basis, so I could easily miss this. ;) 

My code looks like this:
`$form['login'] = [
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('Your login:'),
   '#default_value' => $config->get('login'),
   '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
     ':input[name="settings"]' => array('value' => '1')
    ),
   )
  ];`

Is there anything more to make states work?